# Doing backup from Linux to USB Pen Drive with rsync

Tags: linux, windows, backup, rsync, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to do a backup from Linux to USB Pen Drive with rsync each day and I take home the Pen Drive at night.  I am running the following command but it looks like its update every file every day?

```
rsync -y -r -vv ~/Documents/ /media/PenDrive/xxxx-home/
```

Can someone please tell me if this can be done better I used to just tar of my ~/Documents and cp the file to my Pen Drive but my SA said this would be better but I dont think it is..

and sometimes I am getting this message

rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]

Comment: What format is the filesystem on the pen drive? If it is NTFS then rsync will fail to copy the rights from ext2/3/4. That will cause errors unless you tell rsync not to attempt that. --- Also try `--modify-window=1` (For the logic behind that, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820425)

Comment: format is msdos so it can be used on windows and my mac.. Can you please tell me how to make it not come the rights

Comment: Posted as an answer. Please check if it works **and** read this sites FAQ. (You probably wanted to post to superuser, not to SF).

Comment: what do you think about rsync -rltDvu --modify-window=1 --progress --delete  ~/Documents/ /media/PenDrive/uftwf-home/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rsync --modify-window 1 -a --no-o --no-p --no-g ~/Documents/ /media/PenDrive/uftwf-home/

```
--modify-window 1 because fat "represents times with a 2-second resolution"
--no-o because vfat does not support owners
--no-g because vfat does not support groups
--no-p because vfat does not support permissions
```

Comment: what do you think about rsync -rltDvu --modify-window=1 --progress --delete  ~/Documents/ /media/PenDrive/xxxx-home/

Comment: `--progress` is a cosmetic choice. `--delete` is a personal choice. `-r` and other values can be used. I just specified the flag which solve the problem. If you want to add more options that that should not be a problem.

Comment: do I need -a option?

Comment: I had to use `--modify-window 2`, but otherwise thanks